# android import android-async-http-master have error

Tags: android, asynchronous, github

I got an android project from github named **android-async-http-master**, this is the download link : https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http
but when I import the project to eclipse, it have an error.

I got errors like this:

```
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HeaderElement;
```

so my problem is : the project package name is `com.loopj.android.http` ,where `is the cz.msebera.android.httpclient` package??

Comment: I think you have checked out the development version, get the release version. loopj http client is undergoing a  lot of changes these days because some of it's dependencies were deprecated in Lollipop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you must download this jar  [cz.msebera.android](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cz.msebera.android/httpclient/4.3.6) and then import to your project

if you using android studio just add this  `compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6'` in your .gradle depedencies

hope it help

Comment: when i import import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.......i found that the internet response s more slower than 3s!!!!!!and i am in LAN!!  but when i change the package "cz.msebera.android.httpclient."  to  package "org.apache.http.client" and delete  "httpclient-4.3.6.jar" , the response speed is faster~!!!do you know where the problem is??

Comment: yes you're right it slower than org.apache.http.client but currently i don't know what the reason

Answer (score 1):

in your `app`'s `build.gradle` file, write

```
compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.6'
```

in

```
dependencies{
...//<here>
}
```